# PebbleKit.registerReceivedDataHandler() is undefined in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pebble-sdk

Eclipse does not recognize registerReceivedDataHandler as a method of PebbleKit. 
I have included the following imports into my java file:

```
import com.getpebble.android.kit.*;
import com.getpebble.android.kit.util.*;
```

and have installed pebblekit-3.0.0-eclipse.jar in my libs directory and added it to my build path (it shows in  Java build path/libraries).

Eclipse reports "The constructor PebbleKit.PebbleDataReceiver() is undefined".

The only methods exposed in intelliSense are:

```
PebbleDataReceiver,
FirmwareVersionInfo,
PebbleAckReceiver,
PebbleDataLogReceiver,
PebbleNackRerceiver.
```

I am able to use some of the pebbleKit library since I can send messages from my java file to my watch with:

```
PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble(getApplicationContext(), TACTICIAN_UUID, data);
```

I have posted this query in the pebble SDK help forum as well, with no response.

Eclipse Luna
Windows 7

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I haven't used Eclipse, but I've never had any issues using Android Studio. Have you tried just importing with Ctrl + Shift + O instead of including them manually?

Comment: *I finally gave up on Eclipse, and took the plunge back into Android Studio.  Migrating my pretty mature app was a three-day nightmare, but I'm finally there and making good progress getting my java app to talk to my pebble. It seems that Android Studio has made some pretty major advances sinse I dipped my toes 6 months ago.